# Criteria for breaking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics, free-body-diagram, soft-question

Consider a system with $1$ degree of freedom. Suppose $2$ particles, each of mass $1$ are placed next to each other. The 1st particle is being acted upon by a $100\text{ N}$ force. In general the equations would be (considering 1st particle $m_1$ second particle $m_2$)$-$
$$100-f_r=m_1a_1=a_1$$
$$f_r=m_2a_2=a_2$$
But consider the case when the second particle cannot give a reactionary force so $f_r$ is $0$. In this case,
$$100=m_1a_1=a_1$$
$$m_2a_2=0$$

So what is happening here? Will one ball go through the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there is no reaction force then the particles are called non-interacting. One can pass through the other without disturbing it. This happens, for example, with neutrinos which interact only very weakly. They often pass right through a human or even the earth or sun without interacting with anything.

Comment: @dave Can you also explain how the scenario will change if $f_r$ is not $0$, but less than $50$?

Comment: There is nothing particularly interesting in that case. They are interacting and follow Newton’s laws in the usual way. This could be like pushing a paddle through water or pushing a stick into dirt.